XHR Polling Error Socket.io Chrome extension
I'm trying to communicate with my local server from my chrome extension with scoket.io but I'm getting an XHR Polling Error.
I don't get this error when I simulate a client, I only get it with the chrome extension.
I've also tried using my ip instead of localhost, defining a websocket protocol when creating the server or adding a cors but I always get the same error.

manifest.js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "DogadPrime Alerte",
  "version": "2.0",
  "description": "Ne manquez jamais un live de DogadPrime sur Twitch ainsi que les prochaines vidéos youtube grâce à des notifications instantanées !",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "alarms",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "116",
  "host_permissions": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  }
}

background.js
import { io } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@4.7.1/+esm";


const socketUrl = "http://localhost:3000/";
const socket = io(socketUrl, {
    transport: ["websocket"],
});


console.log("Lancement de l'extension browser");

if (typeof browser === "undefined") {
    var browser = chrome;
}

function showNotificationTwitch(stream) {
    browser.notifications.create('twitch-streamer-alert', {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'icons/icon48.png',
        title: `${stream.user_name} est en live !`,
        message: `Regardez maintenant sur Twitch : ${stream.title}`,
        priority: 2
    });
}

browser.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function (notificationId) {
    if (notificationId === 'twitch-streamer-alert') {
        const twitchChannelUrl = 'https://www.twitch.tv/dogadprime';
        console.log('Ouverture de l\'URL Twitch:', twitchChannelUrl);
        browser.tabs.create({ url: twitchChannelUrl });
    }
});


// Événement lorsqu'une connexion est établie
socket.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('Connexion au serveur');
});

socket.on('platformNotification', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const { platform, status, streamData } = data;
    if (platform == 'twitch' && status == true) {
        console.log('Le streamer est en direct !');
        console.log('Détails du stream :', data.streamData);
        showNotificationTwitch(streamData);
    } else {
        console.log('Le streamer n\'est pas en direct.');
    }

});

socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.log('Erreur de connexion :', error);
});

server app.js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const clientId = process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID;
const accessToken = process.env.TWITCH_ACCESS_TOKEN;
const streamerName = 'sc2skyblue';
const twitchApiUrl = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=${streamerName}`;

let isStreamerOnline = false;

async function checkStreamerLive() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(twitchApiUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': clientId,
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        const currentlyOnline = data.data && data.data.length > 0;

        if (currentlyOnline && !isStreamerOnline) {

            io.emit('platformNotification', {
                platform: 'twitch',
                status: true,
                streamData: data.data[0]
            });
            console.log("Le streamer est en direct. Notification envoyée.");
        } else if (!currentlyOnline && isStreamerOnline) {

            io.emit('platformNotification', {
                platform: 'twitch',
                status: false,
                streamData: null
            });
            console.log("Le streamer est hors ligne. Notification envoyée.");
        }


        isStreamerOnline = currentlyOnline;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erreur lors de la vérification du statut du streamer :', error);
    }
}


const checkInterval = 1 * 60 * 1000; // 1 minute
setInterval(checkStreamerLive, checkInterval);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Un client est connecté');

    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Bienvenue sur le serveur Socket.IO' });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Un client s\'est déconnecté');
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serveur en écoute sur le port 3000');
});


ManifestV3 uses a service worker, which doesn't have XHR. Either use WebSocket API directly (instead of socket.io) or do everything inside the offscreen document.

Thanks for your reply, I'll convert my code using the browser's websocket api and see if that works !
